# How to place double click on Dynamically created list in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on javascript in a project and I'm stuck with a small issue. The problem is I created a page where I use a JSON object to create a list dynamically. Now I need to apply a double click listener to elements in this list. Here is the code so far:

```
    <HTML>
<body onload="createTree()">
    <div id="tree" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:500px;width:300px;float:left;">
    <b>Tree</b><br>
    <script>            

    var JSONObject= {"className":"com.alta.entity.Person","key":"this","modifier":1,"value":"Person [id\u003d1001, firstName\u003dShiju]","level":0,"elementArray":[
        {"className":"java.lang.Long","key":"id","modifier":17,"value":"1001","level":1,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.String","key":"firstName","modifier":17,"value":"Shiju","level":2,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"0","modifier":17,"value":"S","level":3,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"1","modifier":17,"value":"h","level":4,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"2","modifier":17,"value":"i","level":5,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"3","modifier":17,"value":"j","level":6,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"4","modifier":17,"value":"u","level":7,"elementArray":[]}]},{"className":"java.util.ArrayList","key":"addressArray","modifier":1,"value":"[com.alta.entity.Address@10045eb]","level":3,"elementArray":[{"className":"com.alta.entity.Address","key":"0","modifier":1,"value":"com.alta.entity.Address@10045eb","level":4,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Long","key":"id","modifier":17,"value":"1001","level":5,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.String","key":"addressLine","modifier":17,"value":"This is addredss Line","level":6,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"0","modifier":17,"value":"T","level":7,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"1","modifier":17,"value":"h","level":8,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"2","modifier":17,"value":"i","level":9,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"3","modifier":17,"value":"s","level":10,"elementArray":[]}]}]}]}]};


        document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(createUls(JSONObject));
        function createUls(element){
            console.log('looooop');
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = element.key;
            ul.appendChild(li);
            var elementArray = element.elementArray;
            for(var i=0; i<elementArray.length; i++){
                li.appendChild(createUls(elementArray[i]));
            } 
            return ul;
        }                   
    </script>

</body>
```

I intend to place a double click listener on all the list elements that are being created. If any one can please help I would be Extremely grateful. You can copy the Html and see what it does if you have any doubts.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: So you mean like `.dblclick()`?

Comment: yes kind off but the problem is how do i apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#yourliIDhere').dblclick(function () {
  //event handler code here.
});
```

Comment: can u be a little more expressive I dont actually have an id on li. You can see the function being used to create them in the html code called createUls()

Comment: Before the append, var tempID = CreateNewGuid(); $(li).attr('id', tempID); . . . then do the append, then $(tempID).dblclick(function() { //event handler code here. });

Comment: sorry kind of found a way to add id thnx